# Свойство keyCode объекта event устарело, а где аналог?

Tags: javascript

Ребят, Я в недоумении!
Зашел на офф сайт мозилы [event.keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) и там написано что это свойство устарело и на данном этапе в последней версии `firefox` это свойство не работает, выводит оно для всех символом ноли.

Если ли аналог? Я поюзал свойство `event.key` но оно не работает в хроме (последнем) в общем как быть?

Странно, почему `event.key` не работает в хроме?

Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы получить символ в `unicode` до обнаружении проблемы с лисой у меня был такой код:
`String.fromCharCode(event.charCode)`

По вашему, правильно будет проверять свойство `event.key` и если его нет, то использовать код описанный выше? Или есть другое, более правильное, решение?

Comment: `KeyboardEvent.code`

Answer (score 1):

Для получения символа используй `String.fromCharCode(event.which);`

Comment: Спасибо за отклик. Проблема в том, что это свойство тоже устарело! Как быть теперь?!

Comment: Не знаю, у меня оно работает (Firefox 39)

Comment: Да, работает, но свойство устаревшее.

Comment: Тоже недавно видел "устаревшее" событие, не помню какое, и так же думал, а чем заменить. Так что не обращай внимания. Перестанет работать, тогда... Обычно, устаревшие методы оставляют для совместимости.

Comment: В том то и дело, если устарело, то должна быть замена, а иначе бардак. Хотя есть два события key и code. Проверял key, почему то не пашет в хроме

Comment: event.which это работает везде 99%